# Singular curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

How to prove, for example, that there is unique algebraic structure on the curve $\mathbb C P^1 \cup \mathbb CP^1$, where components intersects in 1 point? This is often used in the theory of stable maps in the sense of M. Kontsevich. Fow example, if we take varieties in $V(x,y) \cup V(y,z) \cup V(z,x), \, V(y,z)\cup V(x,z) \cup V(z,x-y) \subset\mathbb A^3_\mathbb C$, the varieties will be different. Maybe the problem is in non-compactness?

Comment: Nice question:+1

Comment: This is not true that the union is unique. You have to suppose the intersection is *transversal*.

Answer (score 0):

In your affine examples the varieties are non isomorphic because the second one is a plane curve, included in the plane $z=0$, whereas the first curve (the union of the three coordinate axes of $\mathbb A^3_\mathbb C$) cannot be embedded in a smooth surface, because its Zariski tangent space at the origin has dimension $3$.
This is a very local obstruction, only depending on the germ at the origin of the first curve, and compactness is completely irrelevant: if you compactify those affine  curves they will definitely remain non-isomorphic!